# collapse navbar list in asp.net core is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

im trying to do collapse navbar list but it did not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark" >
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/sP-cLnVHgvWmW255EghS2d9CnDEvUpY_ZXYaQ7gYsffIC-LFx0QewraeWtgOjJZeynAc=s180-rw" height="30" width="30" />
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbarlist">
               <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
           </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarlist">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a asp-action="details" asp-controller="home" class="nav-link">list</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="home" class="nav-link">create</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div>
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

you can see that i installed bootstrap and jquery.

i also tried to use cdn from bootstrap site but it didnot work too.

Comment: This is a question about Bootstrap, CSS and styles, not ASP.NET Core. Which Bootstrap and ASP.NET Core version are you using? Have you checked your browser's console for any errors?

Comment: did the solution work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the correct path

Change your path from

```
<link href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

To

```
 <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```